# How to bind a hotkey to a specific virtual desktop in Openbox?

Tags: window-manager, openbox

I am using several virtual desktops in **[Openbox](http://openbox.org/wiki/Main_Page)** *main*, *dev*, *media*.
I can switch between them via hotkeys using `DesktopNext` and `DesktopPrevious` calls.

But how can I explicitly bind a hotkey to a specific desktop? So that I could hit `C-A-1` and switch to *main* and `C-A-3` to switch to *media*, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation claims the `GoToDesktop` option may be what you are looking for  ( http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Actions#GoToDesktop )

Example:

```
<keybind key="W-F1">
  <action name="GoToDesktop"><to>1</to></action>
</keybind>
<keybind key="W-BackSpace">
  <action name="GoToDesktop"><to>last</to></action>
</keybind>
<keybind key="W-A">
  <action name="GoToDesktop"><to>next</to><wrap>no</wrap></action>
</keybind>
```

You don't seem to be able to reference desktops by name, but by number:

*The desktop to switch to, starting from 1, or one of the following special values: "current", "next", "previous", "last", "north" or "up", "south" or "down", "west" or "left", "east" or "right".*